# removing and summing up the csv file elements using awk

Tags: awk

I have a big csv file like this example:

```
9,AGCTGTCCTCTT,SCPL
9,AGCTGTCATTTTGTTTCG,SCHFVS
9,AGCTGTAATTGTCGTAAGAGGTCTGCTTATTGTTATTTGTGTGGCCCG,SCNCRKRSAYCYLCGP
9,AGCTGTCCTCTT,SCPL
9,AGCTGTAGTCATTTGGGTTTTATTTGTTTTCATGGCATTGTGGCCCG,
```

1 - In some lines the 3rd column is empty , so they should be removed

2 - Some lines have similar characters in the 3rd column. If that is the case, I want to sum up the values in the 1st column and put it in the 4th column. If the characters in the 3rd column is not repeated in other rows, I want to copy the value of the 1st column into the 4th column.

Expected output:

```
9,AGCTGTCCTCTT,SCPL,18
9,AGCTGTCATTTTGTTTCG,SCHFVS,9
9,AGCTGTAATTGTCGTAAGAGGTCTGCTTATTGTTATTTGTGTGGCCCG,SCNCRKRSAYCYLCGP,9
```

To do so, I made the following code in awk but it does not return the expected output.

```
awk -F "," '{ if(($3 == '') && ({t=3;for(i=2;i<NF;i++){t+=$i==$(i+1)}}t==NF)) { print } }' infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

Do you know how I can change the code to get the expected output?

Comment: Why was the 4th record removed? If because the 3rd field was similar in another record, what happens if the 3rd is similar but the 2nd differs, ie. which one is removed?

Comment: how big is this file (MBytes; number of lines) is this file? do you need to maintain the rows in any particular order?  for rows with a duplicate 3rd field ... will the first 2 fields always be duplicates, too? and if not, which row should be maintained?

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` program. Simple explanation would be, sorting Input_file as per 1st, 2nd and 3rd fields making `,` as a field separator first. Then passing its standard output to `awk` program as an input. In `awk` program setting field separator and output field separator as `,`. Creating variable sum which is keep adding 1st field value to it, until current line is different from previous line.

```
sort -t, -r -k1 -k2 -k3 file | 
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
}
prev!=$0 && prev{
  print prev,sum
  sum=prev=""
}
NF>=3 && $3!=""{
  sum+=$1
  prev=$0
}
END{
  if(sum){
   print prev,sum
  }
}
'
```

Comment: the results does not look like the expected output. only 1st and 2nd columns are there.

Comment: @bzmby, I am sorry I didn't get it. Could you please do let me know what issue you are facing?

Comment: @bzmby, its working fine for me, is your actual file is same as shown samples?

Comment: Works here just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Still not sure why the fourth record was removed from the sample output but this one removes all but the first instance of each `$3`:

```
$ awk -F, -v OFS=, '
NR==FNR {              # on the 1st of 2 runs for the file
    if($3!="")         # remove if $3 empty
        a[$3]+=$1      # sum the $1s
    next
}
($3 in a) {            # on the 2nd run
    print $0,a[$3]     # output
    delete a[$3]       # only first of unique $3s is output
}' file file           # make that 2 runs
```

Output:

```
9,AGCTGTCCTCTT,SCPL,18
9,AGCTGTCATTTTGTTTCG,SCHFVS,9
9,AGCTGTAATTGTCGTAAGAGGTCTGCTTATTGTTATTTGTGTGGCCCG,SCNCRKRSAYCYLCGP,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
BEGIN  { FS="," }
NF < 3 || $3 == "" { next; }
       { score[$3] += $1; orig[$3] = $0; } 
END    { for (g in score) { print orig[g] "," score[g]; } }
```

Should work:

```
ronald:~/tmp$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="," }
NF < 3 || $3 == "" { next; }
       { score[$3] += $1; orig[$3] = $0; } 
END { for (g in score) { print orig[g] "," score[g]; } }' < infile
9,AGCTGTCCTCTT,SCPL,18
9,AGCTGTAATTGTCGTAAGAGGTCTGCTTATTGTTATTTGTGTGGCCCG,SCNCRKRSAYCYLCGP,9
9,AGCTGTCATTTTGTTTCG,SCHFVS,9
```

Instead of sorting the input, a hash is used. If your input is exceptionally large, this might lead to out of memory situations.